# Can only transition State of build to state BuildFinishHooks from states [Configure, TaskSchedule, ReadyToRun]

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am receiving an unexpected Gradle error and I would like to know what it means, the full error message I see is:

```
Can only transition State of build ':game-api' to state BuildFinishHooks from states [Configure, TaskSchedule, ReadyToRun] however it is currently in state ReadyToReset.
```

This error occurs whenever I try to "Rebuild" classes in IntelliJ for a gradle application (JavaExec Gradle task) that I am running in debug mode. Normally Intellij should recompile the changed classes and reload them.

A simplified version of my setup is as follows:

root

- game-api (Kotlin MultiPlatform project)
- game-app (Jvm project)
- game-engine (Jvm project)

Where game-engine is a JVM project that is included as a build in the settings.gradle.kts in root, game-app is a sub-project of root which defines the run task, and game-api is included as a build in the settings.gradle.kts of game-engine.

I have a similar structure setup elsewhere which makes me suspect this has something to do with kotlin multiplatform, I tried finding some more details on this error but I cannot find any other references to it.

Could a gradle guru explain how to troubleshoot this error?